# When to use access modifier private or protected with dependency injection,and which is comfortable for DI using @Autowired or final key

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm still learning programming languages java and spring, during learning, I saw a new way to create dependency injection before I use this type.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
public class CarController {
  final CarServiceImp carServiceImp;
  final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public CarController(CarServiceImp carServiceImp, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
      this.carServiceImp = carServiceImp;
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
  @GetMapping("/getcars")
  public Response getCarByPage(@RequestParam Integer page,@RequestParam Integer size,@RequestParam String price) {
      return carServiceImp.getCarByPage(page,size,price);
  }

  @GetMapping("/car")
  public Response getAllCarFromAutoShop(@RequestParam(name = "autshopId") Integer id) {
      return carServiceImp.getAllCarFromAutoShop(id);
  }

  @PostMapping
  public Response addAllCar(@RequestBody List<Car> carList) {
      return carServiceImp.addAll(carList);
  }

  @PostMapping("/one")
  public Response addOneCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
      return carServiceImp.addOne(car);
  }
}
```

here new way of using DI my question when using access modifier with DI and annotation `@Autowired` with constructor, and which one is comfortable for use by the way thank you for your answer

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
public class CarController {
  private final CarServiceImp carServiceImp;
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public CarController(CarServiceImp carServiceImp, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
      this.carServiceImp = carServiceImp;
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
  @GetMapping("/getcars")
  public Response getCarByPage(@RequestParam Integer page,@RequestParam Integer
   size,@RequestParam String price) {
      return carServiceImp.getCarByPage(page,size,price);
  }

  @GetMapping("/car")
  public Response getAllCarFromAutoShop(@RequestParam(name = "autshopId") Integer id) {
      return carServiceImp.getAllCarFromAutoShop(id);
  }

  @PostMapping
  public Response addAllCar(@RequestBody List<Car> carList) {
      return carServiceImp.addAll(carList);
  }

  @PostMapping("/one")
  public Response addOneCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
      return carServiceImp.addOne(car);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before Spring 4.3 the @Autowired annotation was needed. Since then, it is optional if there is only one constructor.

There are three options for injection in spring: field injection, setter injection and the preferable constructor injection (the one you used).

The constructor injection is to be preferred, because you can be certain that all needed dependencies are injected, if the constructor expects all required dependencies as parameters. This way the class will not be instanciated without the required dependencies.

The visibility of fields in a class should always be private, if not needed otherwise.